# Arguments to run the scala program

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I am completely new to Scala and Spark.May I please know how to run this program from scala commandline
    https://gist.github.com/MLnick/5286475

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 2 cents here. This is how I got it to work, but probably there are better ways to do it:

**1. Replaced your import header with these 2 lines:**

 `import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf} 
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._`

**2. Create a basic build.sbt file:**

name := "Movie Similarities"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.1" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.0.1" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.0.1" % "provided"

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"

**3. Build it:**

sbt package

**4. Run it (make sure spark-submit is on your path):**

spark-submit --class "MovieSimilarities" --master local[4] target/scala-2.10/movie-similarities_2.10-1.0.jar local

**5. Collect the output (for MovieLens 100k):**

Star Wars (1977) | Fathers' Day (1997) | -0.6625 | -0.4417 | 0.9074 | 0.0397

Star Wars (1977) | Jason's Lyric (1994) | -0.9661 | -0.3978 | 0.8110 | 0.0141

Star Wars (1977) | Lightning Jack (1994) | -0.7906 | -0.3953 | 0.9361 | 0.0202

Star Wars (1977) | Marked for Death (1990) | -0.5922 | -0.3807 | 0.8729 | 0.0361

Star Wars (1977) | Mixed Nuts (1994) | -0.6219 | -0.3731 | 0.8806 | 0.0303

Star Wars (1977) | Poison Ivy II (1995) | -0.7443 | -0.3722 | 0.7169 | 0.0201

Star Wars (1977) | In the Realm of the Senses (Ai no corrida) (1976) | -0.8090 | -0.3596 | 0.8108 | 0.0162

Star Wars (1977) | What Happened Was... (1994) | -0.9045 | -0.3392 | 0.8781 | 0.0121

Star Wars (1977) | Female Perversions (1996) | -0.8039 | -0.3310 | 0.8670 | 0.0141

Star Wars (1977) | Celtic Pride (1996) | -0.6062 | -0.3175 | 0.8998 | 0.0220

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out to help me.Much appreciated

Comment: I realized the program is giving me movies that are totally different from Starwars.I think I need to change the program to give me similar results

Comment: When I run spark-submit it gave me a classNotfoundexception.Can you please help me figure it out

Comment: I got the classes working.Its the master URL that is giving me an error nowException in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'local[4]root/target/scala-2.10/movie-similarities_2.10-1.0.jar'

Comment: Hi Sher, please try to separate _local[4]_, that is the master url, from _root/target/scala-2.10/movie-similarities_2.10-1.0.jar_, that is the jar file. Hopefully, your error message should be gone.

Comment: Hey Miguel,the comment is incomplete

Comment: The last parameter of spark-submit ("local") is not consumed by spark-submit, but passed directly to your program. It will become args(0) in your program, that you use as the master when creating the SparkContext.


--master local[4] indicates spark-submit (not your program) where and how to run this request. 


If it's less confusing for you, and you are running an standalone cluster manager (the default), you can omit the --master parameter: 


spark-submit --class "MovieSimilarities" target/scala-2.10/movie-similarities_2.10-1.0.jar local

Comment: Thank you.going to try right now.Thanks so much for your time.Will get back with doubts

Comment: Am getting a  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1242)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:270)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$MovieSimilarities$.main(<console>:111) error

Comment: Hey Miguel,I got it to run.Its just the Math aspect of the program that needs looking into to get the similar movies instead of the dissimilar movies.

Answer (score 0):

Running the program in the gist can be done in several ways depending on your environment.

1. Spark local
2. Spark Cluster (Standalone,YARN, Mesos)
3. Spark REPL

A prerequisite for each of the above is have the necessary Spark libraries. If you run it from the REPL, the libraries are already in your classpath. I personally would recommend doing that because then you will be executing each step of your program and see what is the output of each step.

If you want to deploy this as a standalone program, you need to setup sbt first and create a corresponding build.sbt and project structure for your code. You can follow instructions here to create a standalone program. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#standalone-applications

Comment: Thank you so much.Will get back with doubts